# Is express.static middleware optimal for streaming videos?

Tags: node.js, express, video-streaming

I want to stream videos from a server to a web page with an html video tag. I am using node, and plan to stick with it (no nginx).
For the moment, I am using `express.static` middleware, i.e. [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/), but I am wondering since it is made for serving assets, html pages, etc ... if it is suitable for streaming big videos!?

I took a peak at the code, and it seems that it does things properly : support for `Accept-Ranges` header, etc ... but I lack experience and knowledge about this specific topic, so I can't figure out whether things are as optimal as they could be.

Any suggestion of a better express middleware, or node server for this? purpose?

**EDIT**

I do not need to do anything fancy such adaptative bitrate, etc ... I simply want to make sure that - within the node realm - this setup is optimal to serve a video, since my server is installed on an embedded system with very little RAM available.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "video streaming".  Please elaborate.  `express.static()` supports download of static resources, but doesn't do other intelligent video streaming things such as adaptive resolution based on bandwidth, etc...

Comment: Since you don't have very advanced requirements and node.js supports the basics, it seems like you're at the point where you should just try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to use a proper optimized web server, such as Nginx.

`express.static` is for utility purposes.  Node.js as a whole is useful for building your application server.  If you want to serve static files, use a web server.  Otherwise you have the extra overhead of JavaScript for no benefit.

This goes for any static files, not just video.  The size of the static content really has no bearing here on what's best, as all the servers stream large resources from disk.

Comment: yes, I know, but as said in my question I want to stay with a node-only setup. The reason is that I am on an embedded system with very little memory and I need a dynamic server, which mean I would need to have both nginx + node :(

Comment: @sebpiq As I said, the size of the static content really isn't the deciding factor.  If you must use Node.js as your server, `express.static` is a good choice.  You might consider though that Nginx (and others) are extremely lightweight... can probably use less memory than your Node.js server.  As far as dynamic responses go... if you were actually generating stuff dynamically, you wouldn't be using `express.static`.  There's no reason why you can't use Nginx or similar in front of your Node.js instance, and let Nginx handle clients.  This is a very common configuration.

Comment: yes you are probably right ... or maybe I should just switch to Lua

Comment: No, leave your application where you're comfortable with it.  But, serve your static files with a web server.  Nginx can sit in front of everything.  So, for static files it goes `Client --> Nginx --> (filesystem)`.  For application requests, it goes `Client --> Nginx --> Node.js`.  Nginx sits in front and proxies to your application server, but handles the static stuff directly.  This has the benefit of often reducing load on your Node.js server, when dealing with slower clients.

Comment: nginx and the extra deployment management is simply NOT needed for many applications.  Blindly recommending it without understanding the needs of the application is just not wise.  For example, a simple low-load nodejs server doesn't need nginx in the least to serve a few static resources.

Comment: @jfriend00 Fair enough, and I completely agree with you.  The key word I picked up on in the question was "optimal", but now we know from sebpiq's comments that he doesn't need an optimal solution at all.